# Ошибочное поведение django orm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

Создал модель (изначально в ней было поле ManyToMany, после само объявление было перенесено в другую модель)

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название', unique=True)
```

Сделал миграции, заполнил таблицу. В итоге скрипт не работал. После анализа я нашел окончательную ошибку. (далее консоль)

```
./manage.py shell
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from ask_stranger.models import Tag
>>> t = Tag.objects.get(pk=800)
>>> t
<Tag: Tag object (Chartered accountant12)>
>>> t.name
800
>>> t.id
'Chartered accountant12'
>>>
```

то есть на запрос имени orm выдает id, и наоборот. В самой базе данных проверял, таблица создана и заполнена нормально. Можете хотя бы предположить, в чём проблема?

*Прикрепляю аналогичный запрос из базы данных*:

```
django_db=# select * from ask_stranger_tag where id = 800;
 id  |          name          
-----+------------------------
 800 | Chartered accountant12
(1 row)
```

Comment: Покажите аналогичный запрос напрямую из базы данных, хотим лично убедиться что там правда нормально

Comment: Без проблем. Запрос прикреплён

Comment: Джанго какой версии?

Comment: Может, из-за `unique`... Попробуйте явно указать `primary_key` для id в модели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок выяснилось, что проблема состояла в том, что я реализовал у классов **инициализаторы**, которые сначала вызывали инициализатор суперкласса, после чего инициализировали поля. Из-за этого орм django "путал" названия последних двух полей